# R FeatureHashing: extra value in hashed.model.matrix

Tags: r, matrix, machine-learning

### Summary

Why does a hashed.model matrix produced by FeatureHashing always have a 'tick' (ie. an entry like 1 or 2 or more) in column 1 ?

[image]

### Detail

Delving into what feature hashing does with some simple data, I found 
something I couldn't explain: why does the produced
matrix contain 1 extra value for each record? (always in column 1).

The data:

```
library(FeatureHashing)
df=data.frame( soup=c('broth','pea','tomato','pea','broth'),
               main=c( 'fries', 'potato', 'fries', 'rice','rice') )

> df
    soup   main
1  broth  fries
2    pea potato
3 tomato  fries
4    pea   rice
5  broth   rice
```

Produce the hashed matrix:

```
m=hashed.model.matrix(~.,data=df,hash.size=16,signed.hash=FALSE,
                      create.mapping=TRUE)

5 x 16 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
   [[ suppressing 16 column names ‘1’, ‘2’, ‘3’ ... ]]

[1,] 1 . . . . . 1 . . . . . . . 1 .
[2,] 2 . . . . . . . . . . . 1 . . .
[3,] 1 . 1 . . . . . . . . . . . 1 .
[4,] 1 . . . . . . . 1 . . . 1 . . .
[5,] 1 . . . . . 1 . 1 . . . . . . .
```

Show the mapping:

```
hash.mapping(m)

mainrice mainpotato  mainfries    souppea  soupbroth souptomato  
       9          1         15         13          7          3
```

Now manually translate row one in the dataframe df, using above mapping: row 1 has soupbroth->7 and mainfries->15.  So we expect a tick in columns 7 and 15.

Look at the matrix, row 1:

```
[1,] 1 . . . . . 1 . . . . . . . 1 .
```

We indeed find a tick in column 7 and 15, but also an extra tick in column 1. 
In fact column 1 has a tick for all rows. **Where does this come from ? What it is for ?**

P.S.: For the record: "R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)" / FeatureHashing_0.9

Comment: By tick, do you mean a comma (,)? If so, that's the standard notation for a matrix object (see for example `matrix(1:9, nrow = 3)`. To read more about object representation, see `Matrix` package which lends objects used in `FeatureHashing`.

Comment: No, not comma. An entry like 1, or 2 (or greater), where I wouldn't expect one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first column is the intercept, which is also called bias term in many ML package.

For example:

`m1 = model.matrix(~., df)`

As you can see, the first column of `m1` is named intercept and all its value are `1`.

If you want to remove the intercept column, please try:

`m = hashed.model.matrix(~ . -1, ...)`